# Directory links in Unix?

Tags: unix

Is there a way to create a link in unix that actually go to where the target is?

```
$ cd ~/foo-link
$ pwd
/some/other/directory/foo
```

Or something similar. What I'm trying to solve is that there are some deep paths we often have to go to for doing stuff and I'd like an easy way to go there without having to remember the whole path. Don't want to use a symbolic/ link cause I want to actually end up in that long path.

---

*My concern about using symbolic links is that we have to run some old scripts in these directories and I don't trust them to handle themselves correctly if located "in" a symbolic path. Of course I could be misunderstanding how symbolic links work in unix though...*

Comment: Maybe a `.bashrc` snippet that will call `cd` if `pwd` is the short path?

Comment: Then why don't you `$ cd $(readlink ~/foo-link)` ?

Comment: Perhaps you'd do better attacking the root problem (i.e. you have long paths you don't want to remember) and not asking for your attempted solution instead. [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) could save you time.

Comment: @artistoex Well, first because I didn't know that was possible, but now also because that looked a bit long and annoying. Especially since you'd have to remember to do that as well.

Comment: @slhck Because the path is a bit outside of our control. Annoying legacy software stuff...

Comment: Scripts that can't handle symlinks to directories in the run path almost certainly wouldn't handle directories which exist in multiple locations any better...

Answer (score 2):

Add /some/other/directory to your CDPATH, `cd foo` will then give the desired result.

[more about CDPATH](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~razvan/blog/some-bash-tricks-cdpath-and-inputrc/)

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Didn't know about that. Won't work very well in this case though because the final directory name is rather nondescript and prone to duplicates.

Comment: alias-ing the long path to something shorter is also an option

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: alias gotolongdir="cd /some/other/directory"